# Почему before не прячется за родительский элемент с большим z-index?

Tags: css, z-index

Есть блок с текстом и зеленый кантик реализованный с помощью `before`.
Пытаюсь его спрятать на основной блок с помощью `z-index` и даже `transform:translateZ(0)`, но ничего не выходит.

Раньше думал, что понимаю как z-index и позиционирование работает, ан нет..
Как все же его спрятать без дополнительных оберток?

```css
.main-block {
  background: linear-gradient(119.71deg, #0B0B0B 13.43%, #333333 24.5%, #2D2C2C 28.56%, #121212 46.64%, #363636 65.09%, #121212 82.8%);
  border-radius: 0px;
  min-height: 300px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}

.main-block:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  min-height: 250px;
  width: 75px;
  top: 40px;
  left: -22px;
  background: #95C858;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, ea. Harum perspiciatis quibusdam corrupti dolores, praesentium qui esse nihil magnam iusto. Modi reprehenderit, dolorem nesciunt assumenda reiciendis repellat fugit voluptates!</div>
```

P.S. Хотя проверил, и даже так не работает..

```css
.main-block {
  background: linear-gradient(119.71deg, #0B0B0B 13.43%, #333333 24.5%, #2D2C2C 28.56%, #121212 46.64%, #363636 65.09%, #121212 82.8%);
  border-radius: 0px;
  min-height: 300px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}

.edging {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  min-height: 250px;
  width: 75px;
  top: 40px;
  left: -22px;
  background: #95C858;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-block"><div class="edging"></div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, ea. Harum perspiciatis quibusdam corrupti dolores, praesentium qui esse nihil magnam iusto. Modi reprehenderit, dolorem nesciunt assumenda reiciendis repellat fugit voluptates!</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ нашел здесь - http://qaru.site /questions/15647578/pseudo-element-is-overlapping-the-original-one-even-with-z-index

> Я считаю, что это из-за "контекстов стекирования". Контекст укладки подобен колоде карт, вы можете управлять порядком упорядочивания в одной колоде, но если у вас две колоды, порядок слоев одного не влияет на порядок слоев другого. Псевдоэлементы (::before и ::after) находятся в другом контексте стекирования от самого основного элемента и, как результат, z-index этих псевдоэлементов не сопоставим с z-index основного элемент.

Из [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context):

Каждый контекст стекирования полностью независим от своих братьев и сестер: учитываются только элементы-потомки при обработке стеков.

Изменяя структуру HTML так, чтобы все визуализированные элементы были братьями и сестрами друг с другом и потомками общего родителя, z-index работает так, как должен.

Comment: это называется контекст наложения, если что вот перевод https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: и исходный ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50233846/pseudo-element-is-overlapping-the-original-one-even-with-z-index

Answer (score 1):

В данном примере можно решить задачу, перенеся фон основного блока в after.
И уже распределить с помощью `z-index` слои из псевдоэлементов как требуется.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Не задавайте position relative родительскому блоку, потому что это задаёт новый контекст индексов, из которого уже ничего не вырвется.

Comment: поясните, т.к. мне полюбому нужно позиционирование элементов

Comment: Тут не обойтись без какой-то уступки, чем-то пожертвовать. Или не задавайте z-index родителю, или не задавайте relative, или измените структуру. Если контекст создался (а это в вашем случае делают два свойства), его уже не возможно обойти.